# Qual è il significato di "spiazzante" in questo brano?

Tags: word-meaning

Nel romanzo *Storia di chi fugge e di chi resta* di Elena Ferrante ho letto:

> La Galiani stette ad ascoltarla e fu colpita dalla sua sincerità, dal tono **spiazzante**, dalle frasi in un italiano molto intenso, dall’ironia abilmente governata. Dovette sentire in Lila, immagino, quel qualcosa di inafferrabile che seduceva e insieme allarmava, una potenza di sirena: succedeva a chiunque, successe anche a lei, e la chiacchiera s’interruppe solo quando Gennaro diede uno schiaffo a Marco gridandogli un insulto in dialetto e strappandogli una macchinina verde.

Ho letto le definizioni di "spiazzare" in alcuni dizionari, ma non riesco a capire il significato di "tono spiazzante" nel passaggio precedente. Me lo potreste spiegare?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Spiazzante da ***[spiazzare](http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario_italiano/S/spiazzare.shtml)*** nel senso di:

> - Sorprendere qualcuno, rendendolo incapace di reagire: *spiazzare i concorrenti.* (Sabatini-Coletti)

- Tono spiazzante, ossia  inaspettato, che coglie  di sorpresa chi ascolta.

Comment: Lo coglie di sorpresa e lo lascia incapace di reagire?

Comment: @Charo - la definizione del dizionario si riferisce ai vari effetti che uno spiazzamento  può produrre. Nel caso del brano citato, come ho descritto, penso si riferisca ad un tono spiazzante in quanto inaspettato che probabilmente coglie di sorpresa chi sta ascoltando.